# What do these signs mean in some digital timing diagrams?

Tags: digital-communications

The blue are digital timing diagrams in the below example:

[image]

But what do the black signs represent? I see this rarely on some digital timing diagrams.

Another example:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

~ means a space in time , not to scale , in architectural or Mech dwg they might do that too

```
    but not a time in space... but yet saves some.
```

- It saves space to truncate a timing diagram.
- It means between the wiggles. there is no time scale, it's just compressed.

  - More of the same inside here.
  - No Value added info....

Comment: How should we interpreter it? Is it something like writing 1 2...9 instead of writing 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9  ?

Comment: exactly ......... an abbreviated space

Comment: But in this example here https://i.stack.imgur.com/NfJ1V.png it is 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 segments nothing is abbreviated but yet there is still that sign. Why?

Comment: Only on number 7 there is that sign

Comment: I think that example is wrong

Comment: @panicattack IMHO that example is acceptable--period 7 represents some unspecified number of clock cycles, with data undefined and dval held low. If you wanted to convey a timing diagram where a given state could be held for an *arbitrary* number of clock cycles, how would *you* number the bottom of the diagram?

Comment: @ζ-- I don't understand. What happens at period 7 ? Isnt there one clock during period 7?

Comment: @panicattack The symbol in question is present on the clock in period seven. It means that some arbitrary number of clock cycles have been omitted, just like it means that some portion of time has been omitted from the corresponding other signals.

Comment: It's the yadda yadda symbol?  "Yadda" for short?

Comment: isn't yadda   the ramble ... symbol .. this is the brevity symbol

Comment: @panicattack     `Isnt there one clock during period 7?`  .... the diagram shows a clock transition .... the duration of period 7 and the position of the clock transition are both undefined ... there may also be multiple clock signal transitions during period 7

Comment: In drafting you can text —-//—- to show a compressed repeating pattern